# Node/Express/Jade passing username back to view

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This is my first project with all these technologies, I typically do Angular, but I am working for a charity ( and keen to learn node ).  This is day three.

During a login, this is the method called:

```
schema.statics.authenticateAndLoad = function(req, res, next) {
var userId = req.body.email;
res.locals.userId = userId;
```

This is supposed to store the value so it doesn't need to be reentered.  If login fails, it does this:

```
return next('Login failed. Please enter your details and try again.');
```

Then in my Jade template:

```
    if(locals.userId)
        p Welcome to #{userId}
    else
        p Welcome
```

The actual template has code to try to do what I want:

```
    input(type='text', name='email', id="inputEmail", placeholder="Email", value="#{body.email || ''}")
```

But this does not work.

So, I THINK this means my setting a value in the result is lost when I call 'next', but, because it's also passing in this error object to show on the screen, I'm not sure how I would go about making sure this error shows AND make the value pass through . Right now, my text just says 'welcome' and never 'welcome to xx', this is test code, I'm just proving the value is not being passed through.

My question is, what's the correct way to pass the value through to my template, and ALSO trigger the error message that is being shown.

The code, when I step in to it, goes deep in to Express and checks for errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it is good to see some developers doing charity work.

Typically what you would use is something like this assuming this is a piece of middleware

```
schema.statics.authenticateAndLoad = function(req, res, next) {
       var userId = req.body.email;
       res.locals.userId = userId;


  loginFunction(userdetails,function(error,result){
     //if there is an error you need to render the page or do a redirect to the 
     //login page
     if(error){
          var msg = 'Login failed. Please enter your details and try again.'
          return res.render('login',{userId: userId,error: msg}) 
         //this renders the login page and passes req.body.email to the page as userID and the msg as error
     }

     if(result){

     //if this is correct you return next() as you are saying
     //you may go through
     return next()
     }        
  }
}
```

then on your jade to display the error you use and userID

```
p #{userID}
p #{error}
```

So to answer your question the correct way to send the value to jade you pass it in using this and pass the error in as a variable.

```
 return res.render(template_name,{userId: req.body.email,error: msg})
```

I hope this helps you out